# I want to send emails from a custom module

Tags: 8, emails

I created a module to send emails, but I don't now how to send emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `hook_mail` in your custom `MODULENAME.module` file similar to the following

```
function MODULENAME_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
 $options = array(
   'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
 );
 switch ($key) {
   case 'general_mail':
     $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
     $message['subject'] = t('General mail: @subject', ['@subject' => $params['subject']], $options);
     $message['body'][] = $params['message'];
     break;
 }
}
```

And than to send email anywhere in your code using something like this

```
$mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
$module = 'MODULENAME';
$key = 'general_mail';
$to = "mail@mail.com";
$params['message'] = "This is the message";
$params['subject'] = "Mail subject";
$langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();
$send = true;
$result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);
if ($result['result'] !== true) {
  drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
}
else {
  drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help ,  page show me "your message has been send" but when i check my email i don't find anything

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the deleverability of your server or email or domain in general and it's a separate issue.  Is your server in Gerald able to send email to this address ?

Comment: it throws error "Error sending e-mail from <from_email> to <to_email>: Message body empty, in version 8.9.2

Comment: @EktaPuri Its hard to tell without looking at your code you might want to post a specific new question and refer back to this asnwer.  Not sure if anything has changed since this was implemented but try to update all your email related modules to the latest versions and see if other core emails are send properly.  More info https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_mail/8.9.x

Comment: @GiorgosK I am using plugin webforms, email works fine for this module, only email in custom module has stopped working for version 8.9.2 I am using \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail'). It was working in previous version of drupal possibly i tested it in version 8.8X

Comment: This always throw error  "Error sending e-mail from <from_email> to <to_email>: Message body empty" where as I am passing content is params message